# C# - Running a new process as a user with blank password

Tags: c#, impersonation, system.diagnostics, processstartinfo

I have a child process I spawn from my main application that needs to be run as another local user on a Windows 7 machine.  I would prefer to not set a password on that user account, but it seems that creating a new process with impersonation does not allow for blank passwords or any type of null values.  Anyone know if this is possible?

below was my attempt with passing a blank char:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\PathToExecutable");
System.Security.SecureString psswd = new System.Security.SecureString();
psswd.AppendChar('\0');
psswd.MakeReadOnly();

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.UserName = "NewProcessName";
info.Password = psswd;
info.Domain = "LocalMachine";

Process newProc = new Process();
newProc.StartInfo = info;

newProc.Start();
```

edit:
The error message I recieve

`Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is apparently a known issue that `LogonUser()` fails with a blank password.  I set a generic password for required user accounts in my use case.

Comment: Most likely, this is due to the default security restriction on blank password usage: [Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852174.aspx). If you check the error code, it should mean something like "logon denied due to security policy".

Answer (score 2):

For to do this you have to disable a security policy

1. Go to Control Panel → Administrative Tools → Local Security Policy.
2. Browse the Security Settings → Local Policies → Security Options... Look for "Accounts: Limit local account use of blank password to console logon only".
3. Select Disabled and APPLY

there is other solution here:
https://sites.google.com/site/sqlestream/windows-issue/10-cannot-access-the-shared-folder-due-to-blank-password-not-allowed

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("File Name", "Argument(Optional)")
{
      UserName = "UserName",
      RedirectStandardError = true,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      CreateNoWindow = true
};
using (Process proc = new Process())
{
       proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
       proc.Start();
}
```

and then you will be able to execute a process without declaring an user password

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to impersonate?  `LogonUser()` should allow a blank password.

I don't think calling `psswd.AppendChar('\0')` is the right way to specify a blank password.  Try removing the `SecureString` from your code to see if you can at least make the impersonation work.  Then add the SecureString back in to see if your problem lies there.

***  Edit  ***

Try this:

```
unsafe {
    char* ary = stackalloc char[0];
    SecureString str = new SecureString(ary, 0);
}
```

set `info.Password` to your new SecureString... not sure if you'll have to do that within the `unsafe` context or not.

Comment: If I either choose to not specify any password (omitting `StartInfo.Password`) I receive the same message.  If I go into control panel and modify the User Account and add a password (used the character 'A' for testing), I can pass 'A' as a password through the SecureString and that works fine.  Just didn't want to have to set a password...

Comment: Have you tried calling the overloaded Start() that takes a username, pw, and domain, and passing a blank password there?  I'd expect the same result, but leaving no stone unturned...

Comment: The issue is that StartInfo.Password is a `System.Security.SecureString`, so even the overloaded `Start()` requires `System.Security.SecureString` and not just a string, which can not be blank.
Im pretty close to just setting the dummy password and moving on, the account doesn't need to be protected, its sole purpose is for this impersonation, so a '123' password is fine.  Im just surprised that you can have a User Account with no password, but can not send a blank password here.

Comment: I gave your last edit a shot and got the same error.  For the time being, Im gonna assume that you NEED to have a password specified.

Comment: That stinks  : (  Sorry I couldn't come up with an answer!

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388513/starting-firefox-using-process-start-firefox-not-starting-when-you-set-usename-a) question points out, set `LoadUserProfile` to true in `StartInfo`. Try that out, it might help.

Comment: Yeah, looked through the other post - the executable I am running is also my own - does not rely on User Profiles.  Thanks though.